# Notification in Flutter using Firebase and Node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I develop my app in `Flutter`, the app cares about elderly and it should send notification for each medication. There is also a chat in my app with elderly and his watcher.
Initially, I tried to push notification in chat.
I don't have any idea about `Node.js` but I had to use it with `Firebase` to push notification.
I've use this code in `js` file in `Android Studio`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var firebase = require('firebase');
var app2 = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });
app.use(express.json())

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000...")
})


const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
const FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL= "https://?????.firebaseio.com";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});

export async function sendNotificationChatCreation(){

try{
var payload= {notificationL:{title:'FCM using flutter and node js',
body:'we are fine now'},
data:{click_action:"FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"}}
await admin.messaging().sendToTopic('chat',payload);
} catch(error){
console .log(error);
}
}
```

and then I write the code below in `Chat Class`:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    whoIs(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email);
    super.initState();
    final fbm = FirebaseMessaging();
    fbm.requestNotificationPermissions();
    fbm.configure(
      onMessage: (msg) {
        print(msg);
        return;
      },
      onLaunch: (msg) {
        print(msg);
        return;
      },
      onResume: (msg) {
        print(msg);
        return;
      },
    );
    fbm.subscribeToTopic('chat');
  }
```

but I did not see any notification, so what can I do?
How can I push notification using `Firebase` and `Node.js`?

Comment: Console log the message id after it's sent from your server, do you get a confirmation? What is the response? Have to make sure it's going out first before seeing why there's no change in the app.

Comment: You also have to move your logic from the chat class and put it before you're main function in main.dart, as soon as the app opens, as per the documentation. What version of FCM dependency are you using?

Comment: I think you also need to jsonEncode your payload before it leaves the server.